# SQL - SFW, using IN for where

Tags: sql

I am trying to update values in a table based on if certain parameters are met in another table.
I don't have an IDE to test this -- I can only run the query and no error message are ever display.
I think I am probably making a rookie mistake.. any thoughts?

````
SET t1.customvalue1 = ‘Hello’
WHERE t1.username IN (
SELECT t1.username
FROM table1 t1
JOIN statustable st ON st.userkey = t1.userkey
WHERE st.sitestatus = 22 
AND st.sitetype = 6
AND st.sitename = 'Boom' 
AND st.siteupdate >= now() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
)```
````

Comment: You are missing the "UPDATE" keyword, no?

Comment: ... `UPDATE <tablename> SET ...`

Comment: That and get rid of that fancy quotes. Just use normal 7-bit ASCII (or equivalent) single quotes.